# .of<class>(context) meanning in Dart language

Tags: flutter, dart

what is the meanning of **this line of code :**

```
 CounterBloc counterBloc=BlocProvider.of<CounterBloc>(context);
```

**what does "*.of(context)*" means in dart language?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a method used by `BlocProvider` class. In this case it'll take a `BuildContext context` and search it's ancestors in the Widget tree to find a match of `CounterBloc` exposed above using Provider or Inhered Widgets.

Read about Inhered Widgets or the Provider package.